# Include thumbnail wordpress search results

Tags: wordpress, image, search

I have [the blank-theme wordpress theme](http://digwp.com/2010/02/blank-wordpress-theme/), and would like in the search results also appear as a thumbnail. Is it possible?

search.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

        <h2>Resultados de Búsqueda:</h2>

        <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/nav.php' ); ?>

        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

                <h2><a href='<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID)?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?>

                <div class="entry">

                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

                </div>

            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/nav.php' ); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <h2>Ningún tema encontrado...</h2>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Post the contents of `search.php` template file within this blank theme (if exists)?

Comment: I posted the file search.php Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `search.php` just output the search results title and short description (depends on theme).

To show thumbnail as well just call the wordpress function [`the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) within the loop.

Try this:

```
<div class="entry">

    <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post Thumbnail
            the_post_thumbnail();
        } else {
            //your default img
        }

        the_excerpt(); //your short description
?>
</div>
```

**Full Code:**

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <h2>Resultados de Búsqueda:</h2>

    <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/nav.php' ); ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

            <h2><a href='<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID)?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

            <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?>

            <div class="entry">

                <?php
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post Thumbnail
                        the_post_thumbnail();
                    } else {
                        //your default img
                    }

                    the_excerpt(); //your short description
                ?>
            </div>

        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/nav.php' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <h2>Ningún tema encontrado...</h2>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I replaced the code and I still see the thumbnails, would you do need to edit another file? Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by _I still see the thumbnails_? You don't need to edit another file. If this is working for you.

Comment: In the search results not see any thumbnails, only the text as before. It is as if I had not modified any of the code. :_S

Comment: @Julia Are you sure you have assigned featured image to the search result post?

Comment: Wow, I thought that automatically put, sorry for my ignorance but where the photo is chosen for the post to appear in search results?

Comment: @Julia Goto your Wordpress Dashboard add/edit posts screen and add featured  image from there.

Comment: A thousand pardons, and I found the key, it turns out that my theme had to choose off the outstanding image, I just turn and you can see the thumbnail. Thanks, thanks a billion!

Answer (score 2):

**get_the_post_thumbnail**
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
```

Maybe this can help:
[Add thumbnail to search results ONLY if the thumbnail is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396989/wordpress-add-thumbnail-to-search-results-only-if-the-thumbnail-is-available)

Comment: Thank you very much but I easily mess and do not know where to put that code, I posted mine to see if you can tell me where to put the thumbnails. thank you very much